# How could I configure "IgnoreNullValues" while inserting data into the mongoDB? Globally in the Programm.cs (netcore6)?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core-6.0

In the dotnetCore3.1 I used the following content in the Startup.cs

```
ConventionPack ignoreIfNullConvention = new ConventionPack();
ignoreIfNullConvention.Add(new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true));
ConventionRegistry.Register("ignoreIfNull", ignoreIfNullConvention, t => true);
```

Could somebody please give me an example how this is done using dotnetCore6 in the Programm.cs .
I started with this example  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

This code also works for .NET6.

Follow the link you provided, make potentially nullable properties in the model nullable, such as `Category` and `Author`:

```
public class Book
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string BookName { get; set; } = null!;

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    
    //nullable
    public string? Category { get; set; } 

    //nullable
    public string? Author { get; set; } 
}
```

The rest of the code can be created according to the link you provided.

Finally put the code you used earlier in .NET 3.1 into Program.cs:

```
//...
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    });

//put this before var app = builder.Build()
ConventionPack ignoreIfNullConvention = new ConventionPack();
ignoreIfNullConvention.Add(new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true));
ConventionRegistry.Register("ignoreIfNull", ignoreIfNullConvention, t => true);

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
//...
```

Test Result:

Request:
[image]

Database:

[image]